# can you manage how to add a day in a date in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php
$outerarray = array();
$myeventsmodels=Events::model()->findAll();
foreach($myeventsmodels as $myeventsmodel{
    $innerarray=array();
    $stop_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($stop_date.'+1 day'));
    $innerarray['title']=$myeventsmodel->title;
    $innerarray['start']=$myeventsmodel($date)->start_date;
    $innerarray['end']=$myeventsmodel->end_date;
    $innerarray['url']='/uobportal/#/event';
    $outerarray[]=$innerarray;
}
$events=json_encode($outerarray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
$stop_date = new DateTime('2009-02-15 10:21:00');

echo 'date before day adding: ' . $stop_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

$stop_date->modify('+1 day');

echo 'date after adding 1 day: ' . $stop_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_add` function here the example:

```
$stop_date = "2013-03-15";
date_add($stop_date ,date_interval_create_from_date_string("5 days"));
echo date_format($stop_date,"Y-m-d");
```

the output will be:

```
2013-03-20
```

Reference https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_add.asp

or create a new Date object with existing date plus the number of days you want to add like this:

```
$stop_date = "2010-09-17";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stop_date. ' + 1 days'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stop_date. ' + 2 days'));
```

Output:

```
2010-09-18
2010-09-19
```